# Como cadastrar mais informações na tabela

Tags: php, html, mysql

Esse é meu código:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$rg = $_POST['rg'];
$endereço = $_POST['endereço'];
$conta = $_POST['conta'];
$agencia = $_POST['agencia'];
$operação = $_POST['operação'];
$bandeira = $_POST['bandeira'] ;
//insere dados na tabela
$sql = "INSERT INTO diaristas (nome, rg, edereço, conta, agencia, operação, bandeira, DataCadastro) VALUES ($nome, $rg, $endereço, $conta, $agencia, $operação, $bandeira,)";
//confere se cadastrado ou não.
if (mysqli_query($strcon, $sql)) {
      echo "Profissional Cadastrado com Sucesso.";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($strcon);
}
mysqli_close($strcon);
```

Ele me retorna :

> Error: INSERT INTO diaristas (nome, rg, edereço, conta, agencia,
>   operação, bandeira, ) VALUES (Natan Martins, 1, 1, 1, 1, 001 – Conta
>   Corrente de Pessoa Física, BRADESCO,) You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '�o, conta, agencia, operação,
>   bandeira, ) VALUES (Natan Martins, 1, 1, 1,' at line 1

Não consigo resolver, podem me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Não é a configuração para os caracteres especiais? me parece que ele está reclamando do `ç` em endereço... tenta delcarar eles utilizando uma crase antes e depois do nome da coluna

Comment: observei os caracteres, estava usando ç.
Fiz a troca em tudo desde as variáveis até os parâmetros inclusive no banco para simplificar. ajudou muito. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repare que no erro que enviou logo apos o VALUES falta uma aspa

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�o, conta, agencia, operação, bandeira, ) **VALUES ('', N**atan Martins','171' at line 1

Tente fazer assim colocando *"'.$variavel.'"* (aspas duplas, simples e ponto para juntar)

Troque também o **ç** e o **ã**, porque pode da problema no banco. S

`$sql = "INSERT INTO diaristas (nome, rg, endereco, conta, agencia, operacao, bandeira, DataCadastro) VALUES ("'.$nome.'", "'.$rg.'", "'.$endereco.'", "'.$conta.'", "'$agencia."', "'.$operação.'", "'.$bandeira.'")";`

Answer (score 1):

Esta faltando um parâmetro em VALUES. 
Você colocou uma virgula, mas não colocou o parâmetro